# Lighttpd starts but doesn't work. lighttpd.pid Permission Denied

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, lighttpd

System: **Ubuntu 12.04 Server**

Restarting `lighttpd` show status as `[ OK ]`

But on performing *`netstat -ntulp`* I don't find the lighttpd server to be running.

Here is a screenshot showing the results.

[image: Terminal output of lighttpd restart & netstat]

As you can see checking the syntax of server config reveals that there is a permission error on `/var/run/lighttpd.pid`.

A quick `ls -l` reveals that it is owned by `root` user.

[image: Terminal output of ls -l /var/run/]

So I quickly changed ownership of `lighttpd.pid` to the `server.username/server.group` = `www-data`, and reloaded lighttpd along with a check through netstat.

My efforts have failed. The `pid` keeps changing back to root ownership.
[image: Changing ownership]

Here is my `lighttpd.conf`.
[image: Lighttpd.conf]

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Well the whole question is moot.

I did not set my **`php5-fpm`** socket connections properly. Solved with the following.

First,
`sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

> Now change the listen line to look like this.
>
> > ;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
> >     
> >     *listen = /tmp/php5-fpm.sock*

Second,
`sudo nano /etc/lighttpd/conf-available/15-fastcgi-php.conf`

[image]

Now you just have to restart your `php5-fpm` -> `sudo /etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload`

And,
`sudo /etc/init.d/lighttpd restart`

Reference:

1. http://www.zimbio.com/Linux/articles/IssTANdRWZQ/How+install+Lighttpd+PHP5+MySQL+Ubuntu+12
2. http://kywk.github.io/endroid/linux/ubuntu_LLMP-setup.html